# trigger after update by spesific id

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

hy, I want to use the after update trigger, to make changes automatically in the 'active' column of the password table, when I make changes to the 'active' column of the employee table.

I created a trigger like this:

```
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  UPDATE mstUser_2 u
  SET u.activeEmp=NEW.activeEmp
  WHERE u.activeEmp=OLD.activeEmp

END
```

but the result is changing all ids..

the example table below, when I change id : 3 to 'F' in the employee table and it will automatically change id : 3 in the 'active' column the password table to 'F'

**employee table**

| idx | name | address | Active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nae | dubai | T |
| 2 | nia | mekkah | F |
| 3 | sia | dubai | T |
| 4 | bae | vegas | T |

**password table**

| idx | password | Active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | T |
| 2 | 12345 | F |
| 3 | 12345 | T |
| 4 | 12345 | T |

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to use foreign key:

ALTER TABLE 'employee'
ADD CONSTRAINT 'NAME' FOREIGN KEY ('idx') REFERENCES 'password' ('idx') ON UPDATE RESTRICT

This way you can remove the column active in the password table that is redundant and you can, in one query, using `SELECT * FROM employee NATURAL JOIN password WHERE idx=n` extract all you need.

Optionally you can tell what to do when an empolyee is deleted with ON DELETE, here the mariadb reference page https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/